# What is an analog to duty cycle converter?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, converter

What is an analog to duty cycle convter? A typo or a real thing?

[image]
Source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Accelerometer-block-diagram-12_fig2_267558886

This is the block diagram of the [ADXL202E](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL202E.pdf).

Comment: A PWM generator.

Answer (score 3):

'Duty cycle' in this context is the ratio of 'on' time to total time of a periodic square wave.

The chip outputs two square waves (one for each axis) that have variable 'on' time as a percentage of total time for one cycle.

[image]

T2 is only loosely specified, which allows the use of an RC clock in the chip, but T1/T2 is relatively quite accurate.

---

It is probably implemented internally as an analog triangle or sawtooth generator and two comparators- one for each axis- to compare each of the analog signals to the triangle or sawtooth.

Answer (score 3):

> What is an analog to duty cycle convter? A typo or a real thing?

I think if Analog Devices says it is an "Analog to Duty Cycle (ADC)" that it really is such a thing.

Maybe you remember that if you generate a PWM signal and filter that signal, you would get the average value of the PWM signal. Basically that's a "poor man's" DAC.

This circuit is the opposite, it converts an analog signal (the information is in the voltage) into a PWM signal (the information is in the on/off timing). That will require some circuit where the Duty cycle of the output signal can be influenced by an analog input voltage.

I could think of several ways to implement that. For example convert the input voltage into a current and use that current to charge/discharge a capacitor.

In more detail:

With a differential pair I can split a reference current depending on the input voltage. A low input voltage could split that current 1% : 99 % while a  high voltage splits that 99% : 1%. Then I use those currents to charge and discharge a capacitor: \$I_{charge}\$:\$I_{discharge}\$

So 1% : 99% gives me a low duty cycle (charging takes long).

while 99% : 1% gives me a high duty cycle (discharging takes long).

Sure, that can work :-)

Answer (score 0):

The analog signal is converted to repeating pulse signal where the pulse width carries the acceleration information, it effectively means same as having a PWM signal where the duty cycle carries the output information.

Answer (score 0):

> What is an analog to duty cycle converter? A typo or a real thing?

The diagram shows a 2D accelerometer and a uP.

“The duty cycle outputs can be directly measured by a micro- processor counter, without an A/D converter or glue logic.”

Thus it is digitally computed and stored for each pulse within the range of frequencies and duty cycles in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a real "analog" to duty cycle converter: -

[image]

> *A typo or a real thing?*

It's a real thing if you accept that the UK english spelling is "analogue". It's also a real thing because I've used the LTC6992 and, inside your chip it's going to be something similar. It (or they) exist.